# What is returned from printf?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell, and these are my first steps in trying to understand the syntax. I'm having a very hard time, and the language reference is not helpful, unfortunately.

I tried to do `:type (line_length 1 2 3 4)` and I have red the [reference on printf](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Text-Printf.html) However, it uses symbols with vague meaning instead of words. So, I'm stuck and asking for help.

Put simple: what do I write in place of `???`.

```
line_length :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> ???
line_length ax ay bx by =
            printf ("The length of the line between the points" ++
            "(%d,%d) and (%d,%d) is %.5f\n") ax ay bx by
            ((((fromIntegral (ax - bx)) ** 2.0) +
            ((fromIntegral (ay - by))) ** 2.0) ** 0.5)
```

Comment: Printf is not a good start if you want to learn Haskell.
What type would you like `line_length` to return?

Comment: BTW, `(^ 2)` is better than `(** 2)`, and `sqrt` is better than `(** 0.5)`.

Comment: The language reference certainly isn't a very good learning source for trying to understand the syntax. Have you not tried one of the easy books/tutorials, such as [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) or [YAHT](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/htut/)?

Comment: I would also like to quote from the documentation that you link to: "The return value is either String or (IO a)."

Comment: wvxvw, The answer is not straighforward because `printf` can return a string or it can print the string.  It can do either depending on what you put instead of ???.

Comment: "I actually don't need to return anything from line_length"?? A function that doesn't need to return anything is completely meaningless in Haskell.

Comment: @leftroundabout: I think they mean that the return value isn't important since the side-effect (printing) is what matters.

Comment: @wvxvw: The point is that if you chose `String` as the return type, it doesn't get printed. The only reason you see it in the REPL is because it automatically prints the value of expressions whose type are not `IO a`. When it comes to `IO ()`, leftroundabout's comment makes sense if you consider the IO action as the return value of the function, while your comment is talking about the result of running that action (which in the case of `printf` should indeed be ignored).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The overloaded return type of `printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r` can be a little confusing, but it helps to look at the `PrintfType` instances which are available:

1. First, we have this instance:

   ```
   instance (PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r)
   ```

   This one is used to allow `printf` to take a variable number of arguments. This makes sense due to currying, but you probably won't think of it as the "true" return type of the function. For more information about how this works, see [How does printf work in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828072/how-does-haskell-printf-work/7828634#7828634).
2. Then we have this instance,

   ```
   instance PrintfType (IO a)
   ```

   This means that we can use it as an `IO` action. Similar to `print`, this will print the result to standard output. The result of the action is `undefined`, so you should just ignore it.<sup>1</sup>

   ```
   > printf "Foo %d\n" 42 :: IO ()
   Foo 42
   > it
   *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
   ```
3. And finally,

   ```
   instance IsChar c => PrintfType [c]
   ```

   The type class here is mostly to allow this to be Haskell 98 compliant. Since the only instance of `IsChar` is `Char`, you can think of this as

   ```
   instance PrintfType String
   ```

   but that would require the GHC-specific extension `FlexibleInstances`.

   What this instance means is that you can also just return a `String` without printing it, similar to `sprintf` in C.

   ```
   > printf "Foo %d\n" 42 :: String
   "Foo 42\n"
   ```

So depending on whether you want to print the result or just return it, you can replace `???` with either `IO ()` or `String` in your example.

However, there is another problem with your code in that the compiler is unable to determine which type you wanted the last argument to be, so you have to help it out with a type annotation:

```
line_length :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String
line_length ax ay bx by =
            printf ("The length of the line between the points" ++
            "(%d,%d) and (%d,%d) is %.5f\n") ax ay bx by
            ((((fromIntegral (ax - bx)) ** 2.0) +
            ((fromIntegral (ay - by))) ** 2.0) ** 0.5 :: Double)
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is done to avoid extensions. With extensions, we could write `instance PrintfType (IO ())` and the result would be `()`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When I get stuck with type signatures, I let Haskell do the hard work for me.  That is, I

- write the definition *without a type signature*
- load it into `ghci`
- interactively check the type that Haskell gave it
- copy that signature down (making sure it's what I intended) in the source file