# The true meaning of Lucid's "Term" type

Tags: html, haskell, bootstrap-4, haskell-lucid

I've been playing with Haskell, trying to create a very simple website using Servant and Lucid. At the moment I reached the stage "My code works, I have no idea why". 
I tried creating Bootstrap button. According the the doc, it should be defined as:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

So I found Lucid.Html5 doc: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.11/docs/Lucid-Html5.html and worked out the function that creates a button:

```
button_ :: Term arg result => arg -> result
```

After spending some time trying to work out the correct syntax, I came up with this:

```
-- correctly replicates the html pasted above
button_ [type_ "button", class_ "btn btn-primary"] "Primary"
```

Typically I would have called it a victory and focused on other tasks, but this one looks like a true piece of magic to me.

The doc says "button_" is a function that takes an argument "arg" and returns a value of a generic type "result". However, in my application "button_" clearly takes two arguments and returns "Html ()".

```
-- f                       arg                     arg again ??
button_ [type_ "button", class_ "btn btn-primary"] "Primary"
```

It must do something with the "Term" typeclass, but I'm not sure how to understand it. Can someone help me with this ? I tried loading the module into ghci and inspecting types with ":t", but that didn't help me too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Haskell printf work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828072/how-does-haskell-printf-work)

Comment: Different function, but exact same magic.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry, wasn't aware of the fact :-). I'll review the article you posted and then will close my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Term` typeclass is very convenient—we don't need different `term` functions for creating elements with or without attributes—but can be a bit difficult to understand.

The definition of [`button_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid-Html5.html#v:button_) is

```
-- | @button@ element
button_ :: Term arg result => arg -> result
button_ = term "button"
```

[`term`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid.html#v:term) is a method of the [`Term`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid.html#t:Term) typeclass, and has type:

```
term :: Text -> arg -> result
```

That is: you give it the name of the element, some argument whose type depends on the particular instance, and it returns some result whose type depends on the particular instance. But what instances are available? There are three:

```
Term Text Attribute
-- here, term :: Text -> Text -> Attribute
```

This one is for creating attributes, not elements.

```
Applicative m => Term (HtmlT m a) (HtmlT m a)
-- here, term :: Text -> HtmlT m a -> HtmlT m a
```

This one is for creating elements without attributes. The `arg` we pass as argument to `term` is some piece of html representing the children, and we get another piece of html in return.

```
(Applicative m, f ~ HtmlT m a) => Term [Attribute] (f -> HtmlT m a)
-- here, term :: Text -> [Attribute] -> HtmlT m a -> HtmlT m a
```

This one is the most confusing, and the one that is being used in your code. Here, `arg` is a list of [`Attribute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.12/docs/Lucid.html#t:Attribute) values. That much is clear. But `result` is the type of a function! After passing the attributes, we are left with *another* function `HtmlT m a` -> `HtmlT m a` which allows us to supply the contents of the button ("Primary" in your case).

The `f ~ HtmlT m a` is another wrinkle that isn't really relevant for this answer. It simply says that `f` is equal to `HtmlT m a`. Why not put it directly then? Well, in certain cases it can help [drive type inference](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/) in desirable ways.